# How can I redirect after verify a condition (if)? In php html or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, header

I got an error, i was using header location to redirect after verify a condition and with localhost it was great. But I uploaded the web and now I got an error. I know the problem its because I use header location a lot of times and not in head, but between html and php code.

**What can I use to redirect users to another page in this case? You know between.**

Thank you very much.

Comment: JavaScript: window.location

Comment: If you can handle the condition server side use header("Location: /newUrl");

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your issue properly, however you can always use JavaScript to perform a redirection.

```
if (someCondition) {
    window.location.href = 'newUrl';
}
```

However, it's probably better to perform the redirection server-side. Have you tried [http_redirect](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.http-redirect.php)?